# Validate text that are missing terms

Tags: php, validation

I have a `<form>` where the user can **only remove words** from the input, something like:

```
<input type="text" value="hello world 進撃進撃 lorem ipsum" name="so">
```

When I process the form, I want to ensure that the user only removed the words and didn't add their own terms etc.

So when processing the form, I have the original value:

```
$original_value = 'hello world 進撃進撃 lorem ipsum';
```

And the user edited value:

```
$edited_value = $_POST['so'];
```

How do I validate this?

## What I've tried so far

- I can `expode()` the value into *words* and then cross check if the words in `$edited_value` exists in `$original_value`.
- I can check if all characters users in `$edited_value` exist in `$original_value` but that's a weak validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [strlen](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), here's an example

```
<?php
    $error = false;
    $original_value = 'hello world 進撃進撃 lorem ipsum';
    $originalLenght = strlen($original_value); // get the string length
    $parts = explode(" ", $original_value);


    $newValue = "hello world newword";
    $newLenght = strlen($newValue); // get the new string length
    $newParts = explode(" ", $newValue);

    //Check if the new sentence contains new words using in_array
    foreach($newParts as $newWord){
    if (!in_array($newWord, $parts)) {
        $error = true;
    }
    }

    //Check if the size of the new sentence is > to the original or error is true
    if($newLenght > $originalLenght OR $error){
        echo "Invalid Sentence";
    }else{
        echo "Valid Sentence";
    }
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/JUCtI3)

Comment: This is very interesting! Is there any way to make it a bit less sensitive, by ignoring white spaces and dots so that the following value will validate: `$newValue = "hello world . ";`

Comment: You replace white spaces and dots with something unique, like `|`,  prior to explode.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how? If I replace the whitespaces with `|`, it will not explode the sentence into words because no white spaces are left, if you get my drift.

Comment: `$sentence = str_replace(" ", "|", $sentence);` then explode using `|` instead of space

Comment: I've  to go now, I'll take a look at this after. You may consider replacing the spaces and dots with different characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the tags(words) in an array:

```php
$tags = [
  'tag1' => 1,
  'tag2' => 1,
  // ...
];
```

The user accepts `implode(' ', $tags)` in the `input`.

Then the validation might look like the following:

```php
$valid = true;
foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $_POST['so']) as $tag) {
  if (!isset($tags[$tag])) {
    $valid = false;
    break;
  }
}
```